# Initial Parameters for VARMA models?

Tags: vector-autoregression

I want to estimate parameters of VARMA  model using maximum likelihood estimation using real data. The problem I face with is that I don't know how to set the initial  values for the parameters. I tried to choose randomly but the objective function is always undefined at initial point.

Please, is there any theory about this? I googled and found out that using this program http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/vgxvarx.html **it is not necessary to have initial values for any parameters to be estimated.**. But I don't understnd the theory behind this.

Thank you.